# What is the size of the convolution matrix?

Tags: combinatorics, convolution, image-processing

In my Image Processing course, I had to operate a filter on image. Mathematically it's a convolution between the image $A$ (matrix $M\times N$) and a filer $F$ (matrix $m\times n$):
$$
A\star F
$$
The output is given by:
$$
G(i,j)=\sum_{u=-k}^k\sum_{v=-k}^k A(u,v)F(i-u,j-v)
$$
It made my wonder - what is the size of $G$ matrix? I thought that maybe it should be $(2k)\times(2k)$ but it's not the case.

For example, for:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}9 & 9 & 18\\
27 & 54 & 18\\
18 & 9 & 27
\end{bmatrix}\quad F=\frac{1}{9}\begin{bmatrix}-1 & -1 & -1\\
-1 & 17 & -1\\
-1 & -1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
We get matrix $5\times 5$. What is the formula? I guess we need to count it?

Comment: How is $k$ related to $m$ ,$n$, $M$ or $N$? Also, any restrictions on the size (odd/even numbers)?

Comment: folks actuallly have differing definitions of this notion when the convolution is discrertized. Some folks just sortof "pad" $A$ and $F$ with zeros (imagining theyr'e larger than they are) to fill out all the rest of the elements of $G$. Others use repeating the edge elements of $F$. Some methods just truncate $G$ to be the same size as $A$ and $F$.